# Flush in nginx is not working because of caching

Tags: php, caching, nginx, header, flush

I'm trying to create a progress bar it get some data then do some script and during this process it shows progress loading.

I set before header config with :

```
    // set php execution time to unlimited
    set_time_limit(0);

    // disable cache on server
    @ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 0);
    @ini_set('output_buffering', 0);
    @ini_set('implicit_flush', 1);

    // for Nginx no buffering
    header('X-Accel-Buffering: no');
    header('Content-Encoding: none');

    // set content length to calculate progress percentage
    header("Content-length: 101");

    @ob_end_clean();
```

then there is a loop:

```
   $send = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
        $send .= ' ';
    }
    echo $send;
    flush();
    sleep(1);
```

it sends charters to progress and then flush!

please help me by this!

Comment: if you need more info tell me

Comment: You send out all blanks in a rush and _then_ sleep a single second...

Comment: then should i send single char?!

Comment: I can't tell you, since it is unclear how this is actually meant to be working. In general it looks little promising to attempt to implement a server-only progress bar. There are very good JS based solutions (so client side) which use websockets or AJAX long polls to track the progress of longer lasting tasks.

Comment: i send _n_ char but it's not working too!

Comment: it's an AJAX progress bar too but problem is here about nginx caching